# leaflet KML layer, description popup not working

Tags: leaflet, kml, popup

In this example: http://harrywood.co.uk/maps/examples/leaflet/kml.html a kml layer is put to a leaflet map and be default has popup bindings on the values of the kml name and description tag. However, when I try to adapt this, my layers render well, but don't show  the popups on click event. The kml is well formated (I compared the XML structure of the example kml source and mine) but can't see any relevant difference.. Any pointers what might cause this issue?

Here is the live example http://tiroltrailwebmap.lima-city.de/elbaweb/test.html

KML code snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
<atom:author><atom:name>Locus (Android)</atom:name></atom:author>
    <Style id="track001">
        <LineStyle>
            <color>96ff0000</color>
            <width>4.0</width>
        </LineStyle>
    </Style>
<Placemark>
    <name>No28-Traverse</name>
    <description><![CDATA[<br /><br /><font color="black"><table width="100%"><tr><td><table width="100%"><tr><td align="left" valign="center"><small><b>Länge</b></small></td><td align="center" valign="center">286 m</td></tr>
<tr><td align="left" valign="center"><small><b>Punkte</b></small></td><td align="center" valign="center">12</td></tr>
<tr><td align="left" valign="center"><small><b>Erstellt</b></small></td><td align="center" valign="center">2016-08-31 08:49:41</td></tr>
<tr><td align="left" valign="center"><small><b>Max. Tempo</b></small></td><td align="center" valign="center">0.0 km/h</td></tr>
</table></td></tr><tr><td colspan="1"><hr></td></tr><tr><td><table width="100%"><tr><td align="left" valign="center"><small><b>Min. Höhe</b></small></td><td align="center" valign="center">601 m</td></tr>
<tr><td align="left" valign="center"><small><b>Max. Höhe</b></small></td><td align="center" valign="center">628 m</td></tr>
</table></td></tr><tr><td colspan="1"><hr></td></tr><tr><td><table width="100%"><tr><td align="left" valign="center"><small><b></b></small></td><td align="center" valign="center">Höhenmeter</td><td align="center" valign="center">Distanz</td></tr>
<tr><td align="left" valign="center"><small><b>Bergauf</b></small></td><td align="center" valign="center">8 m</td><td align="center" valign="center">62 m</td></tr>
<tr><td align="left" valign="center"><small><b>Bergab</b></small></td><td align="center" valign="center">-27 m</td><td align="center" valign="center">196 m</td></tr>
<tr><td align="left" valign="center"><small><b>Ebene</b></small></td><td align="center" valign="center">0 m</td><td align="center" valign="center">31 m</td></tr>
<tr><td align="left" valign="center"><small><b>Gesamt</b></small></td><td align="center" valign="center">35 m</td><td align="center" valign="center">289 m</td></tr>
</table></td></tr></table></font>]]></description>
    <styleUrl>#track001</styleUrl>
    <MultiGeometry>
        <LineString>
            <coordinates>
                10.156968,42.786333,633.00
                10.156982,42.786554,633.00
                10.157087,42.786676,626.00
                10.157423,42.786830,613.75
                10.157549,42.786982,611.75
                10.157704,42.787076,607.75
                10.158067,42.787488,602.00
                10.158192,42.787741,596.75
                10.158187,42.787891,596.75
                10.158065,42.788069,602.25
                10.158074,42.788200,601.75
                10.157962,42.788544,611.25
            </coordinates>
        </LineString>
    </MultiGeometry>
</Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give a try to [leaflet-omnivore](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore) plugin.

See also [that example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/omnivore-kml-tooltip/) on mapbox, which builds a popup with content from the `<Placemark>` child tags.

Comment: Thanks, omnivore worked! However, I'm still puzzled by the issue above..

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm 3 years late, but I had this exact issue with  elements and tracked it down to a bug in leaflet-kml, which is reported and fixed here: https://github.com/windycom/leaflet-kml/issues/7

Bonus, if you are using the KML layer in conjunction with a marker cluster, you'll also need: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/issues/970

Comment: Thanks for the hint!